# Java formatting: Keep lines but fix indentation

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, format

I have the following code:

```
DSPOTTGuaranteedUserReachForecastModel model = new DSPOTTGuaranteedUserReachForecastModel(
    mockCache,
    demand,
    mockTargetingDatabaseHelper,
    programType,
    region);
```

The correct indentation should be two indents for each incomplete line. Ideally I would want to my text editor to format my code as such:

```
DSPOTTGuaranteedUserReachForecastModel model = new DSPOTTGuaranteedUserReachForecastModel(
        mockCache,
        demand,
        mockTargetingDatabaseHelper,
        programType,
        region);
```

However, when I try to format it using VSCode, I am getting all the new lines collapsing into one long line instead.

```
DSPOTTGuaranteedUserReachForecastModel model = new DSPOTTGuaranteedUserReachForecastModel(mockCache, demand,
        mockTargetingDatabaseHelper, programType, region);
```

Does anyone know what is the **name** of the rule for preserving line numbers?

Comment: I've update my answer, please have a look.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

About java formatting, [VSCode-Java](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-linting#_formatter) provides an Eclipse formatter file like [Google Style](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/styleguide/gh-pages/eclipse-java-google-style.xml).

The setting you wanted should be something like `java_method_parameters_wrap = split_into_lines`, but unfortunately it's not included in GoogleStyle.xml.

If you're still interested in java formatting, you may figure it out in  [DefaultCodeFormatterOptions](https://javadoc.io/static/org.aspectj/aspectjtools/1.8.12/org/aspectj/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/formatter/DefaultCodeFormatterOptions.html#alignment_for_arguments_in_method_invocation).

**[EDIT]**

Download googlestyle.xml and edit the following settings:

```
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.continuation_indentation" value="1" />
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.join_wrapped_lines" value="false"/>
```

Then in vscode settings.json, set

```
"java.format.settings.url": "<local path to java-google-style.xml>",
```

You can get the formatting style that you want:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of an extension called `Rewrap` which may be what you want to try?

For Rewrap to work automatically, go to the command palette and type: `Rewrap: Toggle Auto-Wrap`

I hope this helps, and if not - hopefully, somebody else can contribute!

Comment: Unfortunately this wordWrap or wrapingIndent does not achieve what I want. Thank you tho.

Comment: What about the reWrap extension - that might be the solution