# Java formatting: Disable line joining?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, google-java-format

I have the following code:

```
 Arrays.asList(new Point2D.Double(1.00, 3.028571712152178),
     new Point2D.Double(2.00, 4.5990231472038055),
     new Point2D.Double(3.00, 4.816365844337747),
     new Point2D.Double(4.00, 6.018445142602669),
```

I am using VSCode with [Google java style guide](https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/eclipse-java-google-style.xml).

When I format this bloc of code, I would like to see the following being produced:

```
 Arrays.asList(new Point2D.Double(1.00, 3.028571712152178), new Point2D.Double(2.00, 4.5990231472038055),
        new Point2D.Double(3.00, 4.816365844337747), new Point2D.Double(4.00, 6.018445142602669),
```

My goal is to configure the formatter to produce this instead:

```
 Arrays.asList(new Point2D.Double(1.00, 3.028571712152178), 
        new Point2D.Double(2.00, 4.5990231472038055),
        new Point2D.Double(3.00, 4.816365844337747), 
        new Point2D.Double(4.00, 6.018445142602669),
```

What is the option to disable the formatter from joining new lines?

Comment: This may cause other side effects, but disabling `org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.join_wrapped_lines` might do the trick.

Comment: Have you ever tried the solution i post to your another similar question: [Java formatting: Keep lines but fix indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65584759/java-formatting-keep-lines-but-fix-indentation/65610174#65610174).